# 3 Table MySQL JOIN and PHP Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, join, pagination

basically I have a search form on my site and it takes a number of parameters to allow users to search. The output expected is retrieved from 3 tables and amalgamated into a rectangle div which displays the users picture and some general stats about them. There is quite a large mysql join and it contains a where clause that is extensive to say the least. I have tried to write php pagination to deal with it to display the output via ordered pages but nothin seems to work.. does anyone have any advice on this kind of pagination... here is my script at pressent.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");
mysql_select_db("DB") or die (mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['submitsearch']))
    {
        $sex1 = $_POST['iama'];
        $sex2 = $_POST['seekinga'];
        $minyrs = $_POST['minage'];
        $maxyrs = $_POST['maxage'];
        $intent = addslashes($_POST['intent']);
        $Edu = $_POST['smarts'];
        $star = $_POST['starsign'];
        $ethnic = $_POST['ethnicity'];
        $bod = $_POST['body'];
        $country = addslashes($_POST['country']);
    }

$sql = $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM
    first_reg AS reg1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
     step2reg AS reg2
ON 
    reg1.unique_sess = reg2.Usessid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    step3reg AS reg3
ON
    reg2.Usessid = reg3.uniquekey
 ORDER BY reg1.id DESC");

$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { 
$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else { 
$pn = 1;
}
$itemsPerPage = 3; 
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
if ($pn < 1) { 
$pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
$pn = $lastPage; 
} 
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT reg2.birthmonth,
    reg2.birthday,
    reg2.birthyear,
    reg2.sex,
    reg1.user_name,
    reg1.state,
    reg1.unique_sess,
    reg1.country,
    reg3.user_image,
    reg3.user_bio
FROM 
    first_reg AS reg1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
     step2reg AS reg2
ON 
    reg1.unique_sess = reg2.Usessid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    step3reg AS reg3
ON
    reg2.Usessid = reg3.uniquekey
WHERE   
    reg2.sex = '$sex1'
AND reg2.seeking = '$sex2'
AND reg2.minage >= '$minyrs'
AND reg2.maxage >= '$maxyrs'
AND reg2.ethnicity = IF('$ethnic' = '', reg2.ethnicity, '$ethnic')
AND reg2.intent =  IF('$intent' = '', reg2.intent, '$intent')
AND reg2.education = IF('$Edu' = '', reg2.education, '$Edu')
AND reg2.starsign = IF('$star' = '', reg2.starsign, '$star')
AND reg1.country = IF('$country' = '', reg1.country, '$country')
AND reg2.bodytype = IF('$bod' = '', reg2.bodytype, '$bod')
ORDER BY reg1.id DESC {$limit}"); 
$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){
$paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
if ($pn != 1) {
    $previous = $pn - 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
} 
// Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
// If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
if ($pn != $lastPage) {
    $nextPage = $pn + 1;
    $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
} 
}
$outputList = '';
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
//Calculate the users AGE from the BIRTHDATE data stored in the DB and output it below as an age
    $dob = $rows['birthday'] . " " . $rows['birthmonth'] . " " . $rows['birthyear'];
    $converted_DOB = floor( (strtotime(date('Y-m-d') ) - strtotime($dob)) / 31556926);
    $resultDisplay = "<div class='searchResult'><div class='memberInfoColumnOne'>";
    $resultDisplay .= "<div style='margin:12px 17px;'><img src='upload/{$rows['user_image']}' width='128px' height='128px' alt='user1' />";
    $resultDisplay .= "</div></div><div class='memberInfoColumnTwo'>";
    $resultDisplay .= "<div class='textInfo'><div class='usernameDisplay'><a href='profile.php?member={$rows['unique_sess']}'><b>". substr($rows['user_name'], 0, 50) . "</b></a><div class='userAgeDisplay'>Age: " . $converted_DOB . " </div></div>";
    $resultDisplay .= "<div class='bioDisplay'>". stripslashes(substr($rows['user_bio'], 0, 90)) . "&nbsp;<b>...</b></div>";
    $resultDisplay .= "<div class='footerDisplay'>
<div style='float:left; color:#fff;'>Location:  ". $rows['state'] ." , " . $rows['country'] . "</div>
<div style='float:right;color:#fff;'>Sex: " . $rows['sex']  . "</div>
        </div>";
    $resultDisplay .= "</div></div></div>";
    echo $resultDisplay;
 }

?>
</div>
<div style="background-color:#CCC;">FSDF<?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
```

Comment: You will benefit from providing a schema for people to test on.

Comment: Instead of " but nothin seems to work.. " you could write what exactly doesn`t work. What is that your script results in?

Comment: It displays the numbers but nothing else.. I am basically looking to see if someone out there has already got a script dealing with multi joins as i dont think my one can handle them. i used it before and it works fine as long as theres no where clause

Comment: on search submit you are displaying the result in same page right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should really be a comment - but it's a bit long.

We'll skip over `$sql = $sql = mysql_query(` for now.

This is *not* a particularly complex bit of SQL, but there are a lot of things wrong with this code.

You fetch *all* the data and sort it from the an unfiltered query to calculate the number of pages and through away the result, then run a *filtered* query to fetch *some* of the data again - but if there's any filtering you will get fewer records.

Really it should be the same filtering on both queries. As to what you fetch from the data, the first method is a very expensive way to get the number of rows a better solution would be to use 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...' better yet would be to to [only run the the second query with a SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND modifer](http://phpdevblog.niknovo.com/2009/06/mysql-pagination-sql-calc-found-rows-vs-count-query.html).

An alternative approach / further enhancement would be to generate a hash of the query and store it with the number of rows and an expiry time in the session - hence avoiding having to check every row every time you run the query.

The way you do your filtering is innefficient.

> AND reg2.ethnicity = IF('$ethnic' = '', reg2.ethnicity, '$ethnic')

This prevents the use of any index on the column. If, instead you build te query dynamically then the optimizer gets to choose the best access path:

```
if ($ethnic) {
    $sql2.="\nAND reg2.ethnicity = '$ethnic'";
}
```

> nothin seems to work

...is not a very useful diagnostic, nor is it an error message.